# How to set pagination for data in a joined table in Supabase

Tags: reactjs, supabase

```
    export async function getPostDetails() {
  let { data: posts, error } = await supabase
    .from("posts")
    .select(
      "postId, postTitle, postDesc,created_at,userId, comment(commentId, id, postId, comment,created_at, profile(username, userAvatar)), likes(id, postId, isLiked)"
    );
  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }

  return posts;
}
```

This is my function for getting the posts, for now i did not set pagination for the posts since it will be easy using range directly but i cannot do the same with the comment since it is a joined table since i want to put pagination for the comments on each post. I am new to supabase so im looking for a better way to query or at least a solution to my problem thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `foreignTable` option of the `range()` modifier like this:

```js
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('posts')
      .select(
        'postId, postTitle, postDesc,created_at,userId, comment(commentId, id, postId, comment,created_at, profile(username, userAvatar)), likes(id, postId, isLiked)'
      )
      .range(1, 2, { foreignTable: 'comment' })
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for! Thanks a lot